# What causes "Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS" errors?

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

I have a PHP batch which was running fine on production until recently when we changed the execution time from 02H30 AM to 01H05. Basically, it sends data to a 3rd party via a secured ftp connection.

I am getting an `Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS` error. I did some readings and it seems old versions of SFTP can trigger this error when file size is too big.

My questions are:

1. What is this `SSH_FXP_STATUS` error precisely?
2. Which side is triggering it? The sender or the receiver?
3. If the servers have different versions of SFTP, can this trigger this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Question 1: Search for "9.1.  Status Response" in this document https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13.txt

As this is a "response" it seems to me that this is caused by the client that tries to connect via ssh to a server which does not answer with a Status Response.

In addition you might want to search for the "SSH_FXP_STATUS" in this document as well. It states when the server returns a response of that type.

hth

alex

Comment: Well, after digging the code, it is triggered when we try to read responses after our puts... Thanks!

Comment: Link above is now broken. Look to this link instead https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13